# How do I explicitly load related entities in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm having a strange issue with EF that I am hoping you can help me with.

I have loaded an object from the database (Campaign) and now I want to loop through one of the related entities that has a one-to-many relationship.

Originally as the code was looping through the collection (ListingImages) it was firing off a single select statement for each image which is obviously not ideal.

I managed to explicitly load all the listing images using this following..

```
dbContext.Entry(campaign.Model.ListingVersion.Listing)
.Collection(x => x.ListingImages)
.Query()
.Include(x => x.Image)
.Load();
```

And then loop through the listing images...

```
foreach (var listingImage in campaign.Model.ListingVersion.Listing.ListingImages) 
{
    _log.Info(listingImage.Image.InsertedDate); 
}
```

This results in one single query going to the DB and returning multiple records (as expected) however when i loop through the collection in my foreach it is also triggering that same (slightly modified) query to go to the database twice. The only difference is that the second query does not have the inner join to the Image table.

Here is the SQL fired off from the .Load()...

```
SELECT [Extent1].[ImageTypeId]   AS [ImageTypeId],
   [Extent1].[Id]            AS [Id],
   [Extent1].[ListingId]     AS [ListingId],
   [Extent1].[ImageId]       AS [ImageId],
   [Extent1].[CapturedDate]  AS [CapturedDate],
   [Extent2].[Id]            AS [Id1],
   [Extent2].[URLHash]       AS [URLHash],
   [Extent2].[Url]           AS [Url],
   [Extent2].[Format]        AS [Format],
   [Extent2].[InsertedDate]  AS [InsertedDate],
   [Extent2].[RequestErrors] AS [RequestErrors],
   [Extent2].[S3Uploaded]    AS [S3Uploaded],
   [Extent2].[QueuePriority] AS [QueuePriority],
   [Extent2].[HasThumbnail]  AS [HasThumbnail]
FROM   [dbo].[ListingImage] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Image] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ImageId] = [Extent2].[Id]
WHERE  [Extent1].[ListingId] = 'b3c18c0c-4401-e511-945a-06045dea07cc'
```

And here is the SQL firied off from the foreach statement...

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Id]           AS [Id],
       [Extent1].[ListingId]    AS [ListingId],
       [Extent1].[ImageId]      AS [ImageId],
       [Extent1].[CapturedDate] AS [CapturedDate],
       [Extent1].[ImageTypeId]  AS [ImageTypeId]
FROM   [dbo].[ListingImage] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  [Extent1].[ListingId] = 'b3c18c0c-4401-e511-945a-06045dea07cc'
```

The first query should provide EF with everything it needs to be able to get data from ListingImages without having to go back to the database... Any ideas how i prevent this second query getting fired off?

Comment: Is there some reason that `dbContext.Listings.Include(l => l.ListingImages)` doesn't work?

Comment: Hi Bradley, I'm actually selecting multiple listings at once so the only way I could use the Include() in the initial query would be something like this... `dbContext.Campaigns.Include(x => x.ListingVersion.Listing.ListingImages.Select(y => y.Image))` Which I don't really want to do as the SQL it ends up generating is really slow....

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue. My query returns multiple listings also, actually, it returns all the listings unless you filter it with a `where` clause.